# How to get the structure of json element?

Tags: sql, json, oracle

does a function exist (or how to create such a function) that take a json element and return the structure.

For instance, I would like a function f that in this case :

```
SELECT f(json_Array (json_object ('a' VALUE 1,json_Array (b valuejson_object ('a' VALUE 1)))= FROM DUAL;
```

returns [a integer, b [ a integer]] or somethings equivalent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Oracle 12.2, You can use `JSON_DATAGUIDE`:

```sql
WITH table_name (value) AS (
  SELECT json_Array(
           json_object (
             'a' VALUE 1,
             'b' VALUE json_Array(
                         json_object ('a' VALUE 1),
                         'abcd',
                         123
                       )
           )
         )
  FROM   DUAL
)
SELECT j.path,
       j.type
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL(
         SELECT JSON_DATAGUIDE(t.value) AS data
         FROM   DUAL
       ) d
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL(
         SELECT *
         FROM   JSON_TABLE(
                  d.data,
                  '$[*]'
                  COLUMNS(
                    path VARCHAR2(200) PATH '$."o:path"',
                    type VARCHAR2(200) PATH '$.type',
                    len  INTEGER       PATH '$."o:length"'
                  )
                )
       ) j;
```

Which outputs:

> | PATH | TYPE |
> | --- | --- |
> | $ | array |
> | $.a | number |
> | $.b | array |
> | $.b[*] | string |
> | $.b.a | number |

If you want something more detailed then you are probably going to have to write your own JSON parser in PL/SQL (or Java and compile it in the database).

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=037dfc6c26cb2ab38423bd939b01b452)*